# Como retornar cálculos realizados em Service para activity?

Tags: android

Gostaria de enviar o resultado de um cálculo de volta para a activity, estava tentando utilizar um Binder conforme me recomendaram, mas não consigo recuperar este valor. Teria como fazer a activity ficar sabendo que o service terminou o cálculo para então pegar o valor?

Minha activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  implements ServiceConnection{

private TextView numero1;
private TextView resultado;
private TextView numero2;
private TextView resultadosoma;
private EditText numero1informado;
private EditText numero2informado;
private Valores valores;
final ServiceConnection conexao = this;
final Intent it = new Intent("Service");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button biniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button bfechar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    numero1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numero1);
    numero2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numero2);
    resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
    resultadosoma = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultadosoma);
    numero1informado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numero1informado);
    numero2informado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numero2informado);





    biniciar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            it.putExtra("numero1", numero1informado.getText().toString());
            it.putExtra("numero2", numero2informado.getText().toString());

            //startService(it);
            Class<Service> classeServico = Service.class;
            bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, classeServico), conexao, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            //classeServico.get
            startService(it);


        }
    });



    bfechar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //stopService(it);
            unbindService(conexao);
            stopService(it);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    unbindService(conexao);
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;

    valores = binder.getValores();

}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    valores = null;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public TextView getNumero1() {
    return numero1;
}

public void setNumero1(TextView numero1) {
    this.numero1 = numero1;
}

public TextView getResultado() {
    return resultado;
}

public void setResultado(TextView resultado) {
    this.resultado = resultado;
}

public TextView getNumero2() {
    return numero2;
}

public void setNumero2(TextView numero2) {
    this.numero2 = numero2;
}

public TextView getResultadosoma() {
    return resultadosoma;
}

public void setResultadosoma(TextView resultadosoma) {
    this.resultadosoma = resultadosoma;
}

public EditText getNumero1informado() {
    return numero1informado;
}

public void setNumero1informado(EditText numero1informado) {
    this.numero1informado = numero1informado;
}

public EditText getNumero2informado() {
    return numero2informado;
}

public void setNumero2informado(EditText numero2informado) {
    this.numero2informado = numero2informado;
}

public Valores getValores() {
    return valores;
}

public void setValores(Valores valores) {
    this.valores = valores;
}
```

}

Service:

```
public class Service extends android.app.Service implements Runnable, Valores{

private static final int MAX = 10;
protected int cont = 0;
private boolean ativo;
private double numero1;
private double numero2;
private double resultado;

private final IBinder conexao = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder{

    public Valores getValores(){
        return Service.this;
    }
}


public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){

    return conexao;
}



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("and","onCreate()");

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("and","onStartCommand()");
    //cont = 0;
    //ativo = true;
    //new Thread(this,"Exemplo Serviço: "+startId).start();

    String valor1 = intent.getStringExtra("numero1");
    String valor2 = intent.getStringExtra("numero2");
    Double numero1 = intent.getDoubleExtra("numero1", 0);
    resultado = Double.valueOf(valor1) + Double.valueOf(valor2);


    intent.putExtra("resultado", resultado);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


public void run(){
    while(ativo && cont < MAX){
        fazAlgo();
        Log.i("and", "Exemplo serviço executando: "+cont);
        cont++;
    }
}

public void fazAlgo(){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("and","onDestroy()");
    ativo = false;


    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public double numero1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return numero1;
}

@Override
public double numero2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return numero2;
}

@Override
public double resultado() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return resultado;
}
```

}

Comment: Parece ser um cálculo relativamente simples para utilizar em um service. Já tentou fazer o cálculo ao passar para a outra activity ou é obrigatório o uso do service?

Comment: Eu estava fazendo apenas um exemplo, para fazer um cálculo mais complexo depois. Se for um cálculo que demore para terminar, colocando para esse processamente ser feito no service o sistema operacional não irá fechá-lo, ou ele terá o mesmo comportamento que se fazê-lo na activity?

Comment: Service é para operações mais demoradas que executam em background, então o uso está correto. A Activity pode receber o resultado através do binder ou através de um broadcast receiver (o service pode efetuar um broadcast do resultado). Se pretende usar o binder, especifique melhor o problema que está tendo. Dizer "não estou conseguindo" não é muito claro.

Comment: Quando o service termina um cálculo, como eu aviso a activity que pode pegar o resultado?

Comment: Nesse caso eu recomendaria um `BroadcastReceiver` para notificar a `Activity` do término do cálculo assíncrono, mas registrar um `Listener` no `Service` também é outra solução. Seria uma forma mais simples do que usar um `Binder`. Posso montar uma resposta em breve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua activity precisa aguardar o resultado ficar pronto, e o service precisa notificar a activity quando finalizar o cálculo. Para isso, ele precisa guardar uma referência da activity, para poder saber quem ele irá avisar. A forma de fazer isso é registrando a activity como listener do service (padrão [Observer](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer)).

Primeiramente, crie a seguinte interface:

```
public interface ReceptorDeResultado {
    public void receberResultado(double resultado);
}
```

Depois, crie um atributo mListener no service que implementa essa interface (só para informação, a letra m no nome é para diferenciar de variáveis locais. mListener é um membro da classe Service - no caso, uma variável de instância):

```
private ReceptorDeResultado mListener = null;
```

Depois modifique a classe LocalBinder para suportar o registro e remoção do listener:

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder{

    public Valores getService(){
        return Service.this;
    }

    public void registerListener(ReceptorDeResultado listener) {
        Service.this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public void unregisterListener() {
        Service.this.mListener = null;
    }
}
```

Agora, faça MainActivity implementar a interface ReceptorDeResultado:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements ServiceConnection, ReceptorDeResultado {
```

Como a classe MainActivity agora implementa a interface ReceptorDeResultado, é obrigada a ter um método receberResultado():

```
public void receberResultado() {
    // Neste método você faz uso do resultado, por exemplo exibindo-o
    // na tela. O código para fazer isso eu deixo por sua conta.
}
```

Agora vamos colocar em uso as preparações que fizemos. Mas antes disso, na classe MainActivity, é necessário tornar a variável binder uma variável de instância e não uma variável local. Portanto, declare-a junto com as outras variáveis de instância:

```
private LocalBinder mBinder = null;
```

e corrija seu uso no método onServiceConnected():

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mBinder = (LocalBinder) service;
}
```

Agora vamos lá. Respeitando o ciclo de vida da activity e evitando memory leaks, iremos registrar a activity como listener do serviço e cancelar esse registro quando a activity for destruída. Então, no mesmo método onServiceConnected() que acabamos de mexer:

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
    binder.registerListener(MainActivity.this);
}
```

Removendo o listener no método onPause (crie este método na classe MainActivity):

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (binder != null) {
        binder.unregisterListener();
    }
}
```

Registrando o listener novamente no método onResume, para o caso da activity ter sido destruída e recriada por exemplo em caso de rotação da tela (crie o método onResume() na classe MainActivity):

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (binder != null) {
        binder.registerListener(this);
    }
}
```

Pronto, o service agora tem um listener (ou observer) para avisar quando o resultado estiver pronto. Vamos fazer isso na classe Service:

```
resultado = Double.valueOf(valor1) + Double.valueOf(valor2);
if (mListener != null) {
    mListener.receberResultado(resultado);
}
```

Voilà! Se tudo deu certo (não testei o código), o service vai informar o resultado calculado para a activity (se ela estiver observando o service naquele momento).

Agora uma ressalva para o futuro. Para cálculos mais demorados, você precisará que seu Service execute esse cálculo em um thread separado (hoje ele roda no thread principal e só permite cálculos rápidos, que não causam obstrução do thread principal). A forma mais fácil de permitir isso é fazer o seu service estender a classe IntentService e não android.app.Service. Isso porque IntentService executa comandos em um thread à parte por padrão. Portanto, quando for implementar seus cálculos mais demorados, estude [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

Comment: Funcionou assim. Muito obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento.

Comment: Se a resposta atendeu a sua necessidade, não esqueça de [aceitá-la](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/357).

Answer (score 1):

O problema que você está tendo é porque esta recuperando os valores antes do `onStartCommand` ter terminado, logo os valores não foram calculados pois o cálculo é assíncrono.

Minha sugestão é usar um `BroadcastReceiver` local, sem expor dados privados para fora do seu aplicativo.

**Lembrando que é preciso declarar a dependência na support library v4, se não puder, use o BroadcastManager, mas ai será global**.

Meu exemplo de Service que usa o `LocalBroadcastManager` para notificar o término de um trabalho assíncrono:

```
public class TheService extends Service {

    public static final String BROADCAST_FILTER = "the_service_broadcast";
    public static final String PARAMETER_EXTRA_KEY = "the_service_key";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Doing Heavy Work...
                    Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
                    broadcast(true);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    broadcast(false);
                }
            }
        }.start();

        return result;
    }

    void broadcast(boolean success) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(BROADCAST_FILTER).putExtra(PARAMETER_EXTRA_KEY, success));
    }
}
```

Exemplo de `Activity` que registra um `BroadcastReceiver` para o broadcast do `Service`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // BroadcastReceiver responsavel por escutar o broadcast do Service
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast from TheService(" + intent.getBooleanExtra(TheService.PARAMETER_EXTRA_KEY, false) + ")", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Todo seu codigo de inicializacao...
        startTheService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Registra o BroadcastReceiver para escutar por broadcast's do Service.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(TheService.BROADCAST_FILTER));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Remove o Receiver quando a Activity for pausada.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    private void startTheService() {
        // Inicia o servico
        startService(new Intent(this, TheService.class));
    }
}
```

Recomendo usar o `onPause` para remover (evitar *leaks* de memória) e o `onResume` para registrar. Caso sua `Activity` seja colocada em *background* o `BroadcastReceiver` será removido e caso a `Activity` volte ao *foreground*  o `BroadcastReceiver` será registrado novamente.

Se você precisar do resultado mesmo sem a `Activity` estar visível (*foreground*), então recomendo remover apenas no `onStop` ou `onDestroy`. Seria válido para guardar o resultado, mas não é recomendado alterar as `View's` nesses casos.